# Can you use special attacks for opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, combat-maneuver

Can you use a Disarm, Shove or Grapple as your OA?  I see no restrictions against it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: This has been answered here for grapple: [Can you grapple a creature as an opportunity attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57368/can-you-grapple-a-creature-as-an-opportunity-attack) and here for shove: [Can you use your Attack of Opportunity to Shove?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79835/can-you-use-your-attack-of-opportunity-to-shove)

Comment: Semi-related: [Can Flame Blade be used to make an AoO](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80686/can-flame-blade-be-used-to-make-an-attack-of-opportunity/80690#80690)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key here is whether the "special attack" requires the **attack action** or just a **melee or weapon attack**. An opportunity attack is a **melee attack**. It is not an attack action. Therefore, special attacks which require an attack action cannot replace it, whereas special attacks which require only a melee attack can.

---

**No for Grapple and Shove**

From [Sage Advice](http://Grappling/shoving%20are%20part%20of%20the%20Attack%20action%20(PH,%20195).%20Take%20the%20Ready%20action%20to%20grapple/shove%20outside%20your%20turn.):

> Grappling/shoving are part of the Attack action (PH, 195). Take the Ready action to grapple/shove outside your turn.

---

**Yes for Disarming Attack** (the fighter maneuver)

Disarming Attack:

> When you hit a creature with a **weapon attack**, you can expend one superiority die to attempt to disarm the target. (PHB 74)

Opportunity Attack:

> you use your reaction to make one **melee attack** against the provoking creature. (PHB 195)

Melee Attacks

> A melee attack typically uses a handheld **weapon** (ibid)

I think that it's fairly clear that an opportunity attack is a weapon attack, and can therefore become a disarming attack if the fighter expends a superiority die.

---

**Yes for the Optional Disarm Rule**
(note that [there is no disarm rule in the PHB](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47648/does-dd-5e-lack-a-general-disarm-rule))

Disarm Contest:

> A creature can use a **weapon attack** to knock a weapon or other item from a target's grasp. (DMG 271)

As above, it only requires a **weapon attack**, not an attack action. However, you will need to ask your DM (if you are not the DM) as to whether they are using this optional rule.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, no and no.

A Disarming Attack requires a Battlemaster manoeuvre and a weapon attack that hits so the Opportunity attack qualifies.

Grapple says "... use the Attack action ..." and Shoving says "Using the Attack action ..."; an opportunity attack uses your *reaction*, not your *action* and specifically not an Attack action.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli Don't quite see what you are getting at: there is a difference between the Attack Action, a melee attack (which could use a spell, a weapon or an unarmed strike), and a melee weapon attack. Grapple and Shove are special attacks that replace an attack when you take the Attack action - not at any other time.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli better take this to chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40475/grapple-and-opportunity-attack